# format date columns when "?" appears in same column

Tags: sas

I have several columns with dates and some entries contain the entry "?" and other entries contain dates in the MMDDYY10. format.

I compare dates at a later point, and have the code that works for that, but the missing entries and "?" cause errors to occur and  observations to be created.

here is my import code:

```
 data WORK.esn_service                               ;
   %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
   infile 'C:\Documents and Settings\richardg\Desktop\Sirius\esn_service.csv' delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
  informat DEACTIVATION_DATE best10. ;
  informat DEACTIVATION_REASON $35. ;
  informat REACTIVATION_DATE best10. ;
  format DEACTIVATION_DATE mmddyy10. ;
  format DEACTIVATION_REASON $35. ;
  format REACTIVATION_DATE mmddyy10. ;
  input

               DEACTIVATION_DATE 
               DEACTIVATION_REASON $
               REACTIVATION_DATE 

   ;
  if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
  run;
```

The two date columns are causing the error. I need to later compare dates, so I cant just pick a random date to replace the problem cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with how you are importing the data.  Once a column is a character variable, it's stuck that way - you have to create a new column to change it.  Either change how you import it to bring it in as numeric, or create a new column for each to force it to be numeric.

If your data has MMDDYY10 in it already (in the CSV file), then you need to use INFORMAT.  INFORMAT controls how SAS reads in the data.

```
data WORK.esn_service                               ;
   %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
   infile 'C:\Documents and Settings\richardg\Desktop\Sirius\esn_service.csv' delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
  informat DEACTIVATION_DATE mmddyy10. ;
  informat DEACTIVATION_REASON $35. ;
  informat REACTIVATION_DATE mmddyy10. ;
  format DEACTIVATION_DATE mmddyy10. ;
  format DEACTIVATION_REASON $35. ;
  format REACTIVATION_DATE mmddyy10. ;
  input

               DEACTIVATION_DATE 
               DEACTIVATION_REASON $
               REACTIVATION_DATE 

   ;
  if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
  run;
```

Comment: using MMDDYY10. forces it to be numeric? Or, do i need to specify some alternative format? Sorry for the question here

Comment: The initial dataset, `esn_service`, has these variables already on it, yes?  They're brought in as character, presumably because you're importing from CSV or Excel and it's scanning the column and finding characters ("?").  `Format` does not change the type of a variable, unless the variable does not exist prior to that statement.

Comment: yes.  Dates are numeric in SAS.  MMDDYY10. is a format that formats a number to be displayed as a date.  How are you importing the data?

Comment: i used import wizard and then copied the code so I could edit it.  The csv is too large to open fully in excel, so i could delete the ?'s there, and I have tried to change format and informatto mmddyy10. and best10., pretty much every combination.  I keep getting errors because of the ?'s

Comment: You should be able to edit the code you copied.  Post that in the original question.  :)

Comment: Edit your question and add the first five or six rows from your CSV file.  You are confusing the meaning of INFORMATs, FORMATs, and data types.  You need to show us the raw data you are trying to read.

Comment: @user2448666 Edited answer to reflect probably the correct result - but definitely post some data if this doesn't work.